# htaccess do not allow to access a file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

[image: enter image descriptenter code hereion here]

This is my file structure. I need to get access to the images folder through a URL and get images. But I can`t access that folder. This is the URL that I need to get access. http://10.0.2.2/careuAppWeb/careu-php/images.  I need to get pictures in the images folder and display it somewhere else.Is there any way that I can get access to that folder and get those images. I think the problem is my .htaccess file.
This is it.

```
     
      Options -Indexes
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
      RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

How can I get access to Images folder.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your attempts, could you please do let us know which url is not working? Or from which url to which url you want to redirect internally more clearly here?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yeah sure. I edited the question

Comment: IMHO I think any request coming from your browser will redirect any request to public folder that's why you are not able to request.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Is there any way that I can fix this.

Comment: Like I asked before and Mr. White has also asked in his comments, please be clear in your requirements in your question.

Comment: "This is the URL that I need to get access `http://10.0.2.2/careuAppWeb/careu-php/images`" - Are you really accessing the directory itself, without a trailing slash, or are you really just accessing the image files within it and this is just a prefix? I've assumed the later.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
> RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
> ```

You can change your mod_rewrite directives to something like the following instead:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^images
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

This creates an exception for any URL to the `/images` subdirectory and rewrites everything else to the `/public` subdirectory.

The first `RewriteRule` you had was superfluous and is handled by the 2nd rule anyway.

This does assume you have an additional `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory that also contains mod_rewrite directives, otherwise you get a rewrite-loop.

Comment: I changed it. But this doesn`t work. I have a htaccess file in public folder as well.You think it may occur as a problem.

Comment: WHat is the URL of the HTML page that is serving these images and what is the URL (value of the `href` attrib) you are using in your page?

Comment: The `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory should not be problem.

Comment: "but it doesn't work" - what happens exactly? Do you get an error? Is the URL rewritten?